# How do I change the 3D view to a 2D view in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I have install Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. It loads a 3D view. I want to change it to 2D .

How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are in the login screen. Hit the gear next to your login name, there you can define which "desktop-setup" is used.